# callbacks on graphics figure zoom/pan etc

Tags: octave

Working with Octave 3.8.2

Been looking at some MatLab code that dynamically regenerates axis tick labels as graph figures are panned/zoomed.  The code includes the following statement to register a callback function

```
...
set(zoom(hAxes),'ActionPostCallback',@ZoomHandler);
...
```

This isn't supported in Octave, I get a message regarding zoom() not yet being implemented,  and googling "octave ActionPostCallback" returns zero useful hits so imagine it isn't either.

Had a bit of a look at the addlistener function and figure/axes properties, but nothing leaped out at me as particularly relevant, Is there currently any feasible way of doing this sort of thing in Octave?

thx.

Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update xticklabels, I would trigger on changes from "xlim". One example:

```
1;
function ZoomHandler (h)
  x = get(h, "xtick");
  set (h, "xticklabel", FILL HERE)
endfunction

plot (1:10)
addlistener(gca, "xlim", @ZoomHandler)
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? On what platform and graphics toolkit?

 I tested out something very similar, using addlistener on "xlim" and wasn't getting my callback handler firing on zoom/pan operations.

Comment: @RichardLang: tested with Octave 4.0.0-rc3 and graphics_toolkit fltk and qt. The gnuplot toolkit of course can't work because the is no feedback channel from gnuplot->octave

Comment: Ok, works for me with fltk. Recon I'd probably initially tried it with gnuplot, I was choping & changing back n forth due to another issue .  

Thanks